# Which is better option OpenXml or Microsft.Office.Interop.Excel to read excel file in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, openxml

I am using .NET 4.6 framework and I have to read multi sheets predefined templated excel workbook in asp.net/c# code and I know two way to solve the problem using either **DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll** or **Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll** assembly.

But I am in confusion which one to use as I don't have expert knowledge to decide.
My questions are; 
What are the pros and cons using them in a solution? 
Is there one better than another?
Could you please explain so that I could pick one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is relatively simple: If you combine "excel file" and "asp.net" in the same sentence, NEVER use Interop.
Interop opens a real excel instance and manipulates it to set / retrieve data.
It's slow, can hang unpredictably, there might be popups which block your program (are you sure you want to overwrite this file?) and it's a resource hog.
DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll works, but it's complex to work with, especially if you have user supplied data sheets, which you want to manipulate.
Third party libraries like EPPLUS are more high level and user-friendly, so I would recommend such library.

Comment: I have two sheets with predefined template columns. Is it ok to use DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll? I don't want to use any third party libraries in my case.

Comment: Probably yes, but it really depends on the complexity of the sheet.

Comment: It is more efficient to use OpenXML SDK then Interop, but the code is a bit more complicated. Also both OpenXML SDK and Excel Interop are third party libraries. If you do not want to use any third party library then you would need to use System.IO.Packaging + System.Xml, there is no other native .NET way to read Excel files, everything else is provided from some third party...